# A good use for the * selector as a compound selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working through some CSS course materials, and the instructor has given some examples of selectors... two examples that were given and caught my attention:`a b {}` and `a * b {}`

I was thinking that `a * b` seems somewhat redundant. To select all elements that qualify 'b' that are descendants of any element (*) that are descendants of 'b', is pretty much just the same as saying that they are descendants of 'a'.

Can anyone enlighten me to the purpose of `a * b`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- `.a * .b` will match .b only if there's some container between the two.
- `.a .b` will also match .b contained in .a as a direct child

```css
.a * .b {
  background: blue !important;
  color: white;
}

.a .b{
  background: red;
}

/*-------------*/

.b {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.container {
  border: none;
}

*{
  font-size: 1.5rem;  
}
```

```html
<label>Case 1 (both rules match)</label>

<div class="a">
  <div  class="container">
    <div class="b">
      target
    </div>
    <div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<label>Case 2 (only rule '.a .b' matches)</label>

<div class="a">  
  <div class="b">
    target
  </div>    
</div>

<hr>

<label>Case 3 (both rules match)</label>

<div class="a">  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="b">
          target
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhh bingo! I see the purpose. Actually seems very useful, as opposed to redundant haha.
They can be stacked I'm guessing?
Thanks very much!

Comment: consider also that each rule has a specificity number bound. It's used when there are several rules colliding on the same css attribute for the same element. Such specificity should be higher for a rule like that having an added * compared to an equivalent rule that doesn't have that added selector. Yes the selector are supposed to be chained adding specificity

Comment: for the sake of completeness.. `.a > .b` will match `.b` only if it's a direct child of `.a`

Comment: Thanks. And it increases specificity also, a useful side effect too. Turns out to be quite a useful operator after all. I'm now a member of the cult of Asterisk. haha ty.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong :) I checked now on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity ... Universal selector (*), combinators (+, >, ~, " ", ||) and negation pseudo-class (:not()) have no effect on specificity. (The selectors declared inside :not() do, however.)

Comment: Thank you for thorough and thoughtful answer, demystifying the asterisk CSS operator.